# Show an indeterminate progress + loading message in fragment while data is loading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

One of the most common use cases in Android development is to display a loading progress and a loading message while fragment data is loading.

The main Fragment class -and its subclasses- have a default empty view which contains an indeterminate progress. However, without the ability to display a loading message -e.g. fetching data-

I would like to know your opinions about the best practices of achieving this use case.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AsyncTask to load data and have it return values that indicate the progress of the task. You can create a view you want to display with a progress bar and then create the asynctask and pass the activity context and that progressbar.

```
public class Loader extends AsyncTask<>{

ProgressBar progress;
Context context;
public Loader(Context context, ProgressBar progress)
{
this.progress = progress;
this.context = context;
}

public Integer doInBackground()
{
    // do your loading here and determine what percent is done and call publishProgress()
}

public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... value)
{
    final Integer progressVal = value;

    Runnable updateProg = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        this.progress.setProgress(progressVal);
    }};

    Handler main = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    main.post(updateProg);

}
```